# How make a per-component zustand store?

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I made a Cat component using a minimal zustand store:

```
import { shallow } from "zustand/shallow";
import { CatStoreSchema, useCatStore } from "./CatStore";

export const Cat = () => {
  const selector = (state: CatStoreSchema) => ({
    meows: state.meows,
    incrementMeows: state.incrementMeows,
  });

  const { meows, incrementMeows } = useCatStore(selector, shallow);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Cat meowed {meows} times</span>
      <button onClick={incrementMeows}>Meow!</button> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Store:

```
import { create } from 'zustand';

export type CatStoreSchema = {
  meows: number;
  incrementMeows: () => void;
};

export const useCatStore = create<CatStoreSchema>((set, get) => ({
  meows: 0,
  incrementMeows: () => set(state => ({ meows: state.meows + 1 })),
}));
```

Now, this works great. But what if I want each component to get their own store? Because this is what happens when rendering multiple cat components in a list:

```
Cat meowed 15 times [Meow!]
Cat meowed 15 times [Meow!]
```

They share the store. I tried reading about providers but could not get my head around it. How can I ensure unique/separate stores per component here?

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar issue and I solved it using context.
For example you could do:

```
export const createCatStore = () => createStore<CatStoreSchema>((set, get) => ({
  meows: 0,
  incrementMeows: () => set(state => ({ meows: state.meows + 1 })),
}));
```

Then in the context provider you can `useRef` to ensure that the store will be initialised one time per component mounted

```
export const CatProvider = () => {
  const store = useRef(createCatStore()).current
  return (
    <CatContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</CatContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -4):

It seems like you don't really need to use Zustand stores for this. You can think of a Zustand store as a global state - a state variable that can be pulled by any component across your application without having to worry about props drilling to pass that state across your application.

If you want the store to have a different value for each component, then you really should just be using React's state. Each instance of your Cat component will then be responsible for handling its own state.